# MySQL "GROUP BY" ignores record order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

We've just migrated a database from a MySQL 5.0 server to a 5.5 server, and simple queries like this seem to no longer work as expected:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM tblTable
        ORDER BY fldField ASC
    ) tmp
    GROUP BY fldField
```

The inner query still returns a properly ordered recordset, but the group by is no longer selecting the first record of that set.

Switching the order to DESC has no affect either, so presumably the group by hasn't switched to selecting the last record.

As far as I can tell, group by is actually just selecting the first record as per the order they were created, rather than the order of the actual recordset. If that makes sense?

I can't seem to find any bug report or changelog note for this so hoping somebody here has ideas please?

Comment: You're relying on an undocumented hack (unless you count the comments section of the relevant page of the manual), but the manual discusses this kind of problem in detail in the section on Rows Holding the Groupwise Max. Incidentally, questions on this topic are the most frequently asked under this tag.

Comment: Further digging - it turns out CentOS 7 actually installs MariaDB, not MySQL, and MariaDB returns the inner recordset as an unordered set meaning that the ORDER BY clause is indeed ignored. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out CentOS 7 ships MariaDB instead of MySQL, and MariaDB ignores the ORDER BY clause of inner queries, leaving the outer query to handle the result-set of the inner as an un-ordered table, for better performance.

There are two options here. Either:

- Add the MySQL Community edition overlay and install MySQL from that instead of installing from the CentOS repository, as per one of the many articles like this one: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7
- Or amend inner queries that have ORDER BY clauses to also have a LIMIT clause, which causes MariaDB to treat the result-set as an ordered table. E.g.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM tblTable
      ORDER BY fldField ASC
      LIMIT 10000000
  ) tmp
  GROUP BY fldField
  ```

Hope this saves somebody else a bit of time.